# Getting Out of Memory when trying to select/retrieve blob pdo php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, out-of-memory, blob

I'm saving many blob images/pdf files in my project using many input files. Then when trying to show the saved data I will have to select all the files together(data and blob) and show it to the user. But i am getting `Out of memory` error/exception when i try to search at least 4 images. When i search for 3 images the select is ok. The total average of the files in KiB is around 90 - 100 for 4 blob files. What is the solution for this problem because i still need to show at least 12 files and I'm stuck in the fourth and i already have this problem

`UPDATE`

I have read that when you add this line

`$PDO->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY, false);`

I will be a solution but when i added this line i didnt get any result from my select anymore

Answer (score 0):

Did you call the mysqli_result->free() function in your while loop or after each successive query?

Comment: i change it to $dbh->free(); because i am using pdo i still get error correct me if i am wrong

Comment: Are you getting php out of memory  or MySQL out of memory?

Comment: Another option to try would be to store the images on the server and not the database and simply store the locations of the files in the database.